# Error undefined function in R ":="

Tags: r

Im writing an R code to calculate the average of a data point for every minute for my given data.

My data frame is

```
TIME                              PRICE
2013-01-01 23:54:54               20133
2013-01-01 23:54:50               20133
2013-01-01 23:53:34               20134
2013-01-01 23:53:40               20131
2013-01-01 22:52:54               20131
2013-01-01 22:52:50               20132
```

I want my resultant data frame to have

```
TIME                              PRICE
2013-01-01 23:54:00               20133
2013-01-01 23:53:00               20132.5
2013-01-01 23:52:00               20131.5
```

I used a code snippet to separate my data into hour and minute.

```
trade_1[, c('Hour', 'Minute') := .(data.table::hour("TIME"), minute("TIME"))
+    ][, .(Avg = mean("PRICE")), .(Hour, Minute)]
```

using package `lubridate`

I get the following error

```
Error in `:=`(c("Hour", "Minute"), .(data.table::hour("TRADETIME"), minute("TRADETIME"))) : 
  could not find function ":="
```

Can someone please help me out?

I have already used `library(lubridate).`

Comment: You need to convert `trade_` to `data.table` .ie. `setDT(trade_1)`

Comment: You need `library(data.table)`

Comment: I get the following error now.

Comment: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @SahityaSridhar Please, [edit] your question and add the output of `dput(trade_1)`. This will help to understand what data type columns `TIME` has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to convert to `data.table` and the quote on variables are not needed

```
library(data.table)
setDT(trade_1)[, c('Hour', 'Minute') := .(hour(TIME), minute(TIME))
        ][, .(Avg = mean(PRICE)), .(Hour, Minute)]
#   Hour Minute     Avg
#1:   23     54 20133.0
#2:   23     53 20132.5
#3:   22     52 20131.5
```

Comment: I get the following error Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @SahityaSridhar  I would assume your `TIME` column to be `POSIXct` class. i.e. `trade_1$TIME <- as.POSIXct(trade_1$TIME)`

Comment: same error is shown

Comment: @SahityaSridhar  I copied the data based on your example

Comment: It works! thanks :)